# React Router loads URL in the address bar but doesn't load the component

Tags: reactjs, routes, components, element, router

My Router changes the path to the wanted address but the element doesn't work and doesn't load the contents of the new component at all. I would be so thankful if you let me know what is wrong with my codes.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./pages/aboutus";
import Contact from "./pages/contactus";
import Services from "./pages/depressionadults";
import Home from "./pages/Home";

export default function Main() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />}>
            <Route path="/pages/deppresionadults" element={<Services />} />
            <Route path="/pages/aboutus" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/pages/contactus" element={<Contact />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

`import React from "react";

export default function Contact() {
  return <h1>this is the homepage</h1>;
}
`
```

I expect I can see the contents of the new component that the url path addresses to.

Comment: You need to `import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client` to show content to browser. And use that `createRoot` and render your app component. like this: `createRoot(document.getElementById("root").render(<Main />) `

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I have already done this but it doesn't work.

Comment: could you post your index.js file? or maybe relevant component related to this issue? or any `Warnings` you are getting in your console, check them out.

Comment: try to remove those `divs` that you wrapped your `BrowserRouter` and leave it as it is. it not required well.

Comment: It's my index.js: `import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import Main from "./Main";

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<Main />);`

Comment: I think there's something wrong with my addressing to the pages. Because now that I entered content to Home, it directly comes to my localhost, pressing Home or not. As Home and others all are in a folder named pages in src, I think my addressing is not ok. I have no warnings at my console.

Comment: @Saba S, Please make sure you have used the <Outlet/> component in the <Home/>component. because, Using the Outlet component allows for nested routing in the application, which means that you can have routes that are nested inside other routes. In this case, the Home component is acting as the top-level parent component for the other components, and the <Outlet/> component allows for the rendering of child components based on their respective routes.

Comment: Thank you all. Yeah, I used <Outlet /> and as previous comments I can solve the problem.